# Add and remove hidden input for each checkbox that is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkboxlist

How can you create a hidden input element when a check box from a check box list is selected and remove it when the check box is unselected. See attached example.

[image: selectable check box list]

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="h4" for="location">
    Industry
</label>

<div class="scrollable">
    <div class="checkbox margin-top-0">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="126">
            Arts, Music
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="127">
            Banking, Finance
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div>
<h5 class="margin-bottom-5">Selected</h5>
<ul>
    <li data-id="127">
        Banking, Finance
        <a >
            <i class="icon-after" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="x"></i>
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" value="127" name="industry" data-id="127">
    </li>
    <li data-id="126">
        Arts, Music
        <a >
            <i class="icon-after" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="x"></i>
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" value="126" name="industry" data-id="126">
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).after('<input type="hidden" >');
    }else{
    $(this).next('input["type=hidden"]').remove();              
    }   
  }             
});
```

In your case you would need to call after or remove functions on ul that you have created.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just a tip for answering questions, remember, your answer should not just be a referrence for the user asking the question. This is a wiki site and your answer should be a reference for everyone visiting this page. Describe in short what your code does, how it works and most importantly, where should it be used.

Comment: How do you include the correct checked value in the hidden field? How can you also use a label beside the hidden input to remove it?

Comment: You can use $(this).value() retrieving value .

Comment: '<input type="checkbox" value="126">
 <label>            
            Arts, Music
        </label>'   Use this design and you can use $(this).next('label').text() to retrieve the text inside label